# How to load Python Dataframe to cloudera Impala?

Tags: python-2.7, impala

getting error while loading the dataframe data to Impala table

```
DB = conn.cursor()
for row in fourth_set:
    SQL = ('''Insert into Boots_retailer(sale_date, product, Assessment, weekno, store_Number, volume, turnover, turnover_missing, Inv_Cubic, XGB, KNN) 
    values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''' )

    Values = row['Sale_date'], row['product'], row['Assessment'], row['weekno'],row['store_number'],
    row['volume'],row['turnover'],row['turnover_missing'],row['Inv_Cubic'],row['XGB'],row['KNN']

    har =  DB.execute(SQL, Values)
    connection.commit()
```

Error is on line `Values = row['Sale_date'], ...`:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting TypeError because you're iterating over the labels of the rows, not the rows themselves. Replace your second line with

```py
for _, row in fourth_set.iterrows():
```